# Accessing Struct From Other Source File

Tags: c, struct

I have two files: `getParams.c` and `tree.c`.

What I'm trying to do is to declare `tnode` from `tree.c` into my `getParams.c`.

I don't remember how to properly include code from other source files.

### getParams.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

tnode *doublyLinked;

addtree(doublyLinked, argv[1]);

return 0;
}
```

### tree.c

```
/*
 *  Tree routines from Kernighan and Ritchie
 *  Chapter 6.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EOS '\0'
#define LETTER 'a'
#define DIGIT '0'

#define MAXWORD 20


struct tnode{         /* the basic node */
     char *word;      /* points to the text */
     int count;           /* number of occurrences */
     struct tnode *left;  /* left child */
     struct tnode *right; /* right child */
};

main(){           /* word frequency count */
     struct tnode *root, *addtree();
     char word[MAXWORD];
     int t;

 root = NULL;
 while((t=getword(word, MAXWORD)) != EOF)
 if (t == LETTER)
     root = addtree(root,word);
 treeprint(root);
} 

... more code
```

### The error I'm getting

```
gcc getParams.c tree.c -o getParams

getParams.c: In function ‘main’:

getParams.c:5:2: error: unknown type name ‘tnode’
```

Could I receive your help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I. You should define the `tnode` structure type in a separate header file and include that header file into both implementation files.

II. This is C, not C++. `struct tnode { };` doesn't automatically define the type name `tnode` - you have to do that manually:

```
typedef struct tnode {
    /* foo */
} tnode;
```

Comment: you're missing an 'e' in `typedef struct`

Comment: @harpun Nah, just testing if fellow SO members pay attention :P

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `tnode` in a shared header and then include it using the following:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```